# What is wrong with my vertex declaration?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

What is wrong with my vertex declaration below? I am using it with instancing. After adding TextureInformation to it, it renders weird and has an epileptical seizure.

```
    public struct VertexInstance : IVertexType
    {
        public Matrix World;
        public Color Color;
        public Vector3 TextureInformation;

        // I use arithmetic here to show clearly where these numbers come from
        // You can just type 28 if you want
        public static readonly int SizeInBytes = sizeof(float) * 23;

        // Vertex Element array for our struct above
        public static readonly VertexElement[] VertexElements = {
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 8, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 2),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 12, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 3),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 16, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 4),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 20, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 5)
        };

        public static VertexDeclaration Declaration
        {
            get { return new VertexDeclaration(VertexElements); }
        }

        VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
        {
            get { return new VertexDeclaration(VertexElements); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have any position information in your vertices? Sorry if this is not applicable since I don't know XNA.

Comment: They are defined as separate instance vertex information.

Comment: erm... if you don't mind me asking. Why are you defining World in your vertices? The point of world is to manipulate the full of model after it's definition. I might not be right, but i am assuming you have 4 Vector4 Vertex elements to carry the Matrix data. This might... ? be the problem? Are you sure it can convert it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offset of the last VertexElement is wrong:

```
public static readonly VertexElement[] VertexElements = {
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 8, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 2),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 12, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 3),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 16, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 4),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 16 + sizeof(uint), VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 5)
};
```